# How can i find all the places included in a range of longitude and latitude in a google maps in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I'm new with dealing with google maps APIs and stuff and I'm looking to get a list of all places (For example restaurants) in a certain area in my country. I have the idea to search in a square shape between longitude and latitude but can't find the right method to do so, as I said I'm new to all of this so please HELP!!

I know that the following code returns the info about the certain place i looked for but I shared it just to let you know how shallow I'm into google maps APIs

P.S. its written in a fragment not an activity

```
Places.initialize(requireContext(), MAPS_API_KEY);
    PlacesClient client = Places.createClient(requireContext());
    String id = "ChIJ0bQ-oJN9HhURWKlT7Zh0Sxc";
    List<Place.Field> list = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS);
    FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(id, list);
    client.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener(fetchPlaceResponse -> {
        Place place = fetchPlaceResponse.getPlace();
        Log.d("Place", "Place found: " + place);
    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Log.d("Place", "No place found: " + e.getMessage());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find places through the radius if you want.

In this line you will find the distance from current location to your restaurants.

```
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition());
     distance = (int)Math.round(distance);
```

in the next line you set the radius.

```
if (distance <= 5) {
            //do  something
        }
```

If you want use square, try use polygone. But i dont know how detect all restaurants inside.

Comment: its not something im looking for but still i can do with it thanks <3